# Can I play a game that's installed into Mint OS in Ubuntu?

Tags: games, mint

Recently I installed Linux Mint OS 15 into my laptop. (I have both Ubuntu 12.04 and Mint 15 in my hard drive)

The question is: can I play a game thats installed into Mint OS in Ubuntu?

Example: I installed 0A.D. on  Mint... then I found out that it would be more convenient to run the game in Ubuntu because all my important files are in Ubuntu. So, is there a way to play 0A.D in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Ubuntu and Mint are both Debian-derivatives and as such most software that's compatible with one is also compatible with the other.

That said, while it's definitely *possible* to run the game in Ubuntu while it's still installed to a Mint partition, there are much simpler ways to transition over. You generally wouldn't want to mess with another OS.

*0 A.D.* in particular is [also in the Ubuntu Software Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/0ad/) and as such easily available to reinstall on Ubuntu itself.

Comment: well its true but i have slow internet connection and i'm also having a problem with the game. When i go to the Ubuntu Software Centre, 0 A.D is installed but it says "8.8 mb" installed ( that game is supposed to be 1 gb ).... also i removed the game and reinstalled but sstill i got the same 8.8 mb. I also used the terminal to remove the game and reinstall but still 8.8 mb... help... so now i'm downloading the game on Mint and hopefully i can run the game in either one OS. anyways is it possible to play a game thats installed into Mint in Ubuntu? thx anyways :D

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options. I'll let you pick which of the two is the saner, safer and conducive to a better gaming experience.

- Install the game in Ubuntu too.
- Launch your copy of Mint from inside a Virtual Machine, wait for it to boot, then launch the game from inside there hoping it doesn't require 3D acceleration.

  ```
  # Assuming your copy of Mint is in /dev/sda2
  # If you get this wrong and boot Ubuntu inside a virtual machine inside Ubuntu itself,
  # disasters _will_ happen.
  sudo kvm /dev/sda2
  ```

Comment: thx, but eerm if i launch Mint in Virtual Machine in Ubuntu, would it be connected to the Mint OS in my hard drive?

Comment: @siddhatthachong Yes, it'd be precisely the same copy of Mint you have installed already. You're quite literally booting it.

Comment: thx but can i just run the game in Mint? Is 0 A.D able to run in Mint ? i checked around Google but I couldn't find any answers.

Comment: @siddhatthachong ...uuuuhh I think you question claimed that you _do_ have it installed on Mint?